# ElasticSearch7.15.2 Date range search using Java Api

Tags: elasticsearch, lambda

I am trying to search the documents using a date range filter along with some keywords. I couldn't find any java api samples to do so. Could you please help me.
Normal search works with the following code: But I am after a date range filter search.

```
SearchResponse<JsonNode> search = esClient.search(s -> s
                    .index(index)
                    .query(q -> q
                            .match(f -> f.field(searchKey).query(searchValue).fuzziness(fuzziness).operator(Operator.And))),
            JsonNode.class);
```

But not sure how to create a range query in the similar manner. The following rest query works but unable to convert it to the java api.

```
GET: https://localhost:9200/index_01/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "date_at": {
                "gte": "2020-06-10T00:00:00Z",
                "lte": "2021-06-10T23:59:59Z",
                "boost": 2.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Version details:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works. Please suggest if there is any better option.

```
final String json = "{ \"column_date\": {\"gte\": \"2018-02-02T15:08:28Z\", \"lte\": \"2021-06-23T11:35:01.120Z\"}}";
    final JsonpMapper mapper = new JsonbJsonpMapper();
    final JsonParser parser = mapper.jsonProvider().createParser(new StringReader(json));
    final JsonData data = JsonData.from(parser, mapper);
    final JsonValue value = data.toJson(mapper);
    SearchResponse<JsonNode> search = client.search(s -> s
            .index(index)
            .query( q -> q.range(value)), JsonNode.class, userDn);
```